# Script for mass URL shortening of a static txt file with various content including URLs, in PHP?

Tags: php, file, url

Title should say it all, but here it is:

1. I have a text file, written for javascript, which acts as a database. It looks very similar to a RSS feed, in that it has various elements like titles and URLs.
2. I need to make the file smaller, and the URLs take the most space, so only a URL shortener can help, something like  the V.GD or IS.GD service (has API instructions)
3. I'm not sure what language it should be in, I'm used to PHP.
4. The script has to copy and remove URL's from the list, shorten them by using a web service API, and put the new URL in the place of the older, and at the end of the list it has to export the new file. All the URLs are nice and clean, of course.

Comment: What have you attempted already?

Comment: Nothing, I'm not sure how to approach it. And I feel guilty for just posting here and exploiting users.

Comment: well for starters you can use bitly for your url shortener. API can be found at http://davidwalsh.name/bitly-api-php (that is just an example i found on google.)

Comment: I looked in to is.gd which is shorter, they have a nice API, too.

Comment: When you say 'I have a text file, written for javascript...', is this json?